# Incorrect foreign-key being generated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a foreign key between RoomMission.LobbyId > RoomLobby.LobbyId. I have attempted to do this using below code in the "RoomMission" method.

```
b.HasOne<RoomLobby>(e => e.RoomLobby)
.WithMany(d => d.RoomMissions)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.LobbyId);
```

This produces the migration below which is almost correct but rather than create an additional column ("RoomLobbyLobbyId"), I need it to use the existing "LobbyId" in "RoomMission". Any thoughts on what I maybe doing incorrectly?

```
table.ForeignKey(
name: "FK_RoomMissions_RoomLobbies_RoomLobbyLobbyId",
column: x => x.RoomLobbyLobbyId,
principalTable: "RoomLobbies",
principalColumn: "LobbyId",
onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

**Models:**

```
public class RoomId
{
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RoomMission
{
    public int RoomMissionId { get; set; }

    public int LobbyId { get; set; }
    public RoomId Lobby { get; set; }

    public int StageId { get; set; }
    public RoomId Stage { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public RoomId Room { get; set; }
    
    public virtual RoomLobby RoomLobby { get; set; }
}

public class RoomLobby
{
    public int LobbyId { get; set; }
    public RoomId Lobby { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoomMission> RoomMissions { get; set; }
}
```

**ModelBuilder:**

```
private void RoomId(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RoomId>(b =>
    {
        b.HasKey(u => u.RoomNumber);
    });
}

private void RoomMission(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RoomMission>(b =>
    {
        b.HasKey(u => u.RoomMissionId);
        b.HasIndex(u => new 
        { 
            u.LobbyId, 
            u.StageId, 
            u.RoomId 
        }).IsUnique();
        b.HasIndex(u => u.LobbyId).IsUnique(false);
        b.HasIndex(u => u.StageId).IsUnique(false);
        b.HasIndex(u => u.RoomId).IsUnique(false);
    });
}
    
private void RoomLobby(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RoomLobby>(b =>
    {
        b.HasKey(u => u.LobbyId);
        b.Property(u => u.LobbyId).ValueGeneratedNever();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships are saying that a RoomMission and a RoomLobby both have a RoomId entity linked to them. There is not a navigation property between RoomLobby and RoomMission. If we create a link between RoomMission and a RoomLobby then we can use the LobbyId as a FK constraint in the RoomMission, making the RoomLobby the parent of the RoomMission. I think you have some problems with your mapping of the domain to your model, but this should fix your foreign key issue

```
public class RoomMission
{
    public int RoomMissionId { get; set; }

    public int LobbyId { get; set; }
    public virtual RoomLobby Lobby { get; set; }

    public int StageId { get; set; }
    public RoomId Stage { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public RoomId Room { get; set; }
}

public class RoomLobby
{
    public int LobbyId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoomMission> RoomMissions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this has resolved the issue with the extra column being generated. Just curious is there is a way of having both RoomMission and RoomLobby use the same RoomId entity but setup a navigation property between them to use LobbyId?

Comment: Yes you can add them like a linking table, so both the RoomMission and RoomLobby are connected to each other via the RoomId, this would mean add a reference to RoomId in both RoomMission and RoomLobby, and then include 'many' navigation properties to the RoomId. I would suggest reading the EF Core docs as they have all of this covered in alot of detail.